# Single @Query not matching same results than aggregate multiple @Query

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm using Spring Data JPA 1.11.8 with Eclipselink running on a Weblogic12C connected to an Oracle12 BDD.
I need help understanding why this @Query (10 results):

1)

```java
@Query("SELECT r FROM R r WHERE " +
            "r.status = com.package.Status.PENDING AND (" +
            "( (r.type = com.package.Type.TYPE_B OR r.type = com.package.Type.TYPE_C) AND r.adminOp.code = :code ) OR " +
            "(r.type = com.package.Type.TYPE_A AND r.adminAsking.code = :code) )")
List<R> findAll(@Param("code") String code);
```

Is returning different results than the sum of these three (9 results):

2)

```java
@Query("SELECT r FROM R r WHERE r.status = com.package.Status.PENDING AND r.type = com.package.Type.TYPE_A AND r.adminAsking.code = :code")
List<R> findAllTypeA(@Param("code") String code);
```

3)

```java
@Query("SELECT r FROM R r WHERE r.status = com.package.Status.PENDING AND r.type = com.package.Type.TYPE_B AND r.adminOp.code = :code")
List<R> findAllTypeB(@Param("code") String code);
```

4)

```java
@Query("SELECT r FROM R r WHERE r.status = com.package.Status.PENDING AND r.type = com.package.Type.TYPE_C AND r.adminOp.code = :code")
List<R> findAllTypeC(@Param("code") String code);
```

I'm not sure if I'm missunderstanding an SQL concept, or it's JPQL related... but it's getting me crazy.
First @Query is returning records that matches querys 3 and 4 but records from query 2 are not presents.

SQL Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE R (
  UUID NUMBER(19) NOT NULL,    
  TYPE VARCHAR2(50) NULL,    
  STATUS VARCHAR2(50) NULL,
  ADMINOP_UUID NUMBER(19) NULL,    
  ADMINASKING_UUID NUMBER(19) NULL,  
  CONSTRAINT PK_R_REPRESENTACIO PRIMARY KEY (UUID)
);

CREATE TABLE ADMIN (
  UUID  NUMBER(19) NOT NULL, 
  CODE VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (UUID)
);
```

plus FK...

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "R")
public class R {

    @ManyToOne
    private Admin adminOp;

    @ManyToOne
    private Admin adminAsking;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private com.package.Status status;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private com.package.Type type;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADMIN")
public class Admin {
        @Id
        private Long uuid;
        private String code; 

        ....
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

*PS: at first asking 3 querys was acceptable, but now I need to be a Page< R > result and I need to query all records at once.*

*PS2: I've tried to analyze native SQL generated but neither understand what's wrong :S*

*PS3: I've also tried running native SQL with same results*

Comment: "r.status = PENDING". is that valid sql ? strings need quotations. Or is it a column name ? 
Please provide table structure with sample data. Help us help you.

Comment: Sorry, I've simplified the querys for better reading. It's an enum. I've provided sql and entities.

Comment: Reading unformatted SQL/JPQL is awefull errorprone, so start by formatting your code so that terms enclosed in paranthesis can easily seen. And then identify the elements that show up as results in one statement but not the other one. This should lead fairly easy to either a solution or a way better focused question.

Comment: @JensSchauder what do you mean by unformatted? The elements that are not shown in first statement, as I'm saying in the question are the ones that are returned by query numered "2)"

Comment: unformatted: long lines that don't fit in the view port; no identation; multiple opening parens in a single line; multiple closing parens in a single line.